# Bitwise operation to find if a number exists in an array

Tags: arrays, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This question has been asked multiple times but the suggested answers aren't exactly what I'm looking for.

> Question:  Is there a way to figure out if an array contains a given
>   number?
>
> Assumption:   Elements in the array are guaranteed to be
>   unique.  The array does not have all the elements over a range.  Array
>   is Unordered. The program that wrote the array is the one that is
>   performing the check. So before writing the array it can do some
>   preprocessing to be held in memory.

I'm trying to come up with an approach that doesn't require to hold the elements in memory nor to load the elements from disk in small chunks. Is there an approach similar to "bitwise XOR approach to find the 1 duplicated element in an array on unique numbers". The reason is: I have numbers in groups and stored on disk, I want to load only the group that has the number at hand. I am looking for something in the lines of holding something like XOR of all the elements in the group, then based on the number at hand and the XOR value determining if the group has the number.

Comment: So you have an array of an undefined programming language, and you want to do a bitwise operation on the entire array without loading the file from disk or putting anything in memory? I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using cpp but not sure why it matters in this case. I'm trying to load only the array that has the number at hand and I need to find which array has it before loading. I want to reduce the memory usage as much as possible, not putting nothing in memory.

Comment: You have to load something to check its value. You cannot ask a hard disk whether there is a value at position x (let alone in a file). You have to load it into memory and check the value there. You can do that in chunks to save memory, but you have to process the file. Also, if you found solutions that didn't work for you, mention them. Maybe we can help get them running for you.

Comment: Have added additional information to the question to provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this probabilistically with a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which is based on a hash table.

Hash tables work by storing elements in an array, indexed by the hash of an element. When storing numbers, you might take the number x%10 for example. Then, your hash table might have 10 slots to put 10 numbers in there.

In this case, you only want to know whether a number exists, so each slot might only need a single slot. Using this simplistic example, if a group contains the numbers {5, 17, 18, 76}, the hash table, with 10 bits, would have the bits at index 5,6,7,8 set, and the other bits would be 0. Then, when you want to know if this group has the number 91, you would know that the group does not have this number. However, if you wanted to know if the group has the number 35, you would find that the bit is set. In this case, you only know that the group **might** have this number. This uncertainty is caused by a **hash collision**, when two distinct elements happen to have the same hash. You can reduce this uncertainty by making the hash table larger, so that there are more potential hashed values, and less chance for a collision. However, this still has a non-trivial potential for error, even if your hash table is quite large, eg. 1000-10,000 slots.

A bloom filter helps to reduce this uncertainty further while minimising the memory (slots) required. While in the simple hash table, for each element you insert, you only set 1 bit in the hash table, with the bloom filter, you can set multiple bits in the hash table. To do this, you have multiple hash functions, eg. `f(x), g(x), h(x), ...`, which tell you which bits to set.

In an example with three hash functions, and 20 slots, you might have `f(x)=x%20`, `g(x)=floor(x/20)%20`, `h(x)=((x%7)+f(x))%20`. Suppose you want to insert 3 numbers - 35, 171, 82 into the hash table, then you would set the following bits:

- For 35, set bits 15, 1, 0
- For 171, set bits 11, 8, 14
- For 82, set bits 2, 4, 7

Now, suppose you want to check if the number 80 is present. The relevant bits are: 0, 4, 3. You notice that although the bits 0 and 4 are set, bit 3 is not, therefore, you know that 80 is not in the group.

If you select the number of hash functions optimally, fewer than 10 bits per element are required in the bloom filter for <1% false positive rate. With 3-5 bits per element, you can still get <~50% false positive rate. Since we are counting bits, you can easily have a bloom filter with 1024 bits (using memory equivalent to 32 4-byte integers), and store 100-200 elements while still having very low false positive rates.